# How to get string before a particular symbol within a string

Tags: regex, vb.net, string-function

Is there any way in vb.net to get the username from an email address?

For example, I've a string variable and it consists of value `tracywilly@gmail.com`, here I need to get the username i.e `tracywilly` is my expected output

```
Dim email_addr as string
Dim usr as string
email_addr = "tracywilly@gmail.com"
```

Comment: Searching the ampersand and then using substring ?

Comment: This probbaly won't be enough to produce a username.  A username should be unique within your application and if two different users with email addresses of `tracywilly@gmail.com` and `tracywilly@example.com` both register, they shouldn't both have a username of `tracywilly`.  After removing the end of the email address, you need to check to see if `tracywilly` username exists and (assuming the email address isn't already associated with a different user account/username), add a numeric suffix such as `tracywilly1` and repeat the check. etc. until a username that hasn't been used is found.

Comment: @MattWilko yes, that was an obvious mistake ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using `split()` or  `regex` in vb.net

see the following methods

1.) `split()` function:

```
 Function username(ByVal str As String) As String
        Dim arStr As String()
        arStr = str.Split("@")
        username = arStr(0)
        Return username
    End Function
```

2.) `regex`:

```
Function username_1(ByVal str As String) As String
    username_1 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(str, "^.*?(?=@)").ToString
    Return username_1
End Function
```

---

How does it work?

```
Dim email_addr as string
Dim usr as string
email_addr = "tracywilly@gmail.com"
usr = username(email_addr)
usr = username_1(email_addr)
```

---

[`Live Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CxFe28)

Comment: Thanks for the details and this is exactly what I was looking for, God bless!!